# Wraping of counter in input capture

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, timer, code, overflow

I am doing an input capture on STM32F401RE on TIM1 CH1, CH2, CH3, CH4.
On each channel when a capture happens the ccr1, ccr2, ccr3 and ccr4 will store the value according to the CNT register at that instance.
Now I have to find which channel was first to be triggered, then 2nd, 3rd and 4th. Then I subtract values of 2nd from 1st, 3rd from 1st and 4th from 1st.

To find the triggering order, as I am upcounting the greater the CCR value higher the triggering order.
But the problem occurs when some channels are triggered after it wraps around.(65534, 65535, 65536, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5....).So one channel triggers on 65535 and the rest of the 3 channels trigger on 4, 8 and 10.
Currently, the solution I am implementing is checking whether the subtraction of any register gives a value above 1000 which means triggering has happened in the transition from 65536 to 0, 1, 2. Then do 2 calculations first: by finding difference with 65536 of the >1000 ccr value register ;
second: finding the difference with 0 for the <1000 ccr value register. Then adding the difference as absolutes.
The maximum difference I can get is of 30 pulses, therefore have used 1000.

Is there any better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's perfectly fine.

An alternative is to use the overflow interrupt to count these.